# Shape builder not working..!

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

My shape builder is not working it is not lining any thing .. why is this happening ??? + instead of puls sign with the arrrow  this sign is comming with the arrow .

Comment: My car quit running! What's wrong with it?

Comment: Hi there and welcome Amit to GDSE! You should ask for more clear and give more details and tell how to try. Screenshot or GIFs shots of what and how you tried, would be helpful to fix your problem with the Shape Builder tool. As WELZ mentioned in his answer, check your layers to see if they are locked or not. Create a new document and try the Shape Builder tool on new objects to see if your problem happens again or not.

Answer (score 1):

This likely means that your layers with those shapes are locked and/or you haven't selected your paths.

In order to use the Shape Builder Tool, you need to have first selected the paths you wish to work with.